# How can I automate application installations that have dialog boxes that need input?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to install the downloaded application programatically, hence I am using apple script for the same since am working on Mac.

Here I've downloaded the Adobe AIR Installer app from adobe site which is in downloads folder and am trying to install the same with the below applescript code. Here when the Adobe AIR setup dialog box opens, I need to click on "I Agree"  button to install the app.
With the below code am not able to click on the "I Agree" button, even i dont have Xcode Accessibility Inspecter do inspect the element. Pls guide me the script to handle the "I agree" button.

```
try

    tell application "Finder"

        activate

        open application file "Adobe AIR Installer.app" of folder "Applications" of startup disk

        set this_image to open this_file

        delay 5

        tell application "System Events"

            click button "I Agree" of window "Adobe AIR Setup"

        end tell

    end tell

end try
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Try to use more description question titles, as that is the first thing people see. I've changed yours to give you an example of what it could look like for any of your future questions.

Comment: thanks Steen for valuable suggestion..

Answer (score 1):

You could try GUI scripting the commands with delays in-between clicks, but it's a little bit of work.  Since the Adobe installer doesn't support clicking from applescript, you will need to download [ExtraSuite](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/9730/extra-suites/) and follow along with [this previous MacScripter post](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=12445).

To get pixel coordinates, start up the installer without AppleScript and type '⌘ + shift + 4' to get the crosshairs with pixel location (usually used for taking screenshots).  Write down the coordinates for the first button and then hit 'esc' and move to the next button.

This is a pretty painful way to get the job done but there aren't many other alternatives that I know of.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. Also with that I have got one more thing to do.. after doing the botton action for installing Adobe applications, can we track  the status of progress bar which is installing the app?? if so how to achieve? pls guide..

Comment: I'm not sure if AppleScript can do this because it cannot activate the installer windows.  You could always use [Éxpose](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2503) or [Mission Control](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4689) to view all windows. Otherwise maybe the tell block with `set visible_apps to application processes whose visible is true` from the MacScript link will work?

Comment: Have you found the answer useful? I have noticed that you have not accepted any answers on any of your questions. You should learn to contribute back to SO. The author has taken time to answer your query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Adobe installers don't use Cocoa and aren't scriptable. You might have better luck with [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/). It's based on matching bitmaps and doesn't depend on any underlying framework.